# Optimise function on two criteria in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to optimise an exponential model by minimising the sum of squares, however I can't work out how to optimise using two separate criteria.

I need to find values for "a" and "b" that minimise the output of the function. I have entered estimates in the code below, but need the output of this code to tell me the sum of squares (already printing), but also values for "a" and "b" when the model was correctly optimised.

```
 c <- c(0.08, 0.17, 0.25, 0.33, 0.41, 0.49, 0.57, 0.65, 0.73, 0.81, 0.88, 0.96, 1.04, 1.11, 1.19, 1.26)

  my_fun <- function(a, b, c){
    predVar1 <- a * (1-exp(-c/b))
    sum((predVar1 - c)^2)
  }

  a <- 9
  b <- 1.4

  my_fun(a, b, c)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some rearranging based on how I'm familiar with using optim.  Also, I changed `c` to `d` because I don't like messing with accidentally overwriting the `c()` function.

```
d <- c(0.08, 0.17, 0.25, 0.33, 0.41, 0.49, 0.57, 0.65, 0.73, 0.81, 0.88, 0.96, 1.04, 1.11, 1.19, 1.26)

my_fun <- function(parameters, d){
  a <- parameters[1]
  b <- parameters[2]
  predVar1 <- a * (1-exp(-d/b))
  return(sum((predVar1 - d)^2))
}

a <- 9
b <- 1.4

results <- optim(c(a, b), my_fun, d = d)
results$par
#[1] 700.8850 700.4793
results$value
#[1] 4.37461e-07
```